# how to implement join in linq to sql query

Tags: linq-to-sql

how to implement join in linq to sql query

Comment: possible duplicate of [JOIN and LEFT JOIN equivalent in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013031/join-and-left-join-equivalent-in-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some samples based on your problem:

[LINQ To SQL Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688085.aspx)